# How do I loop the whole program?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at coding so i want to ask for help in a simple program/game I want to create

I'm trying to create a simple scramble game and I've almost finished it...
I want to loop my whole program but I'm having a problem with it..
Any suggestions on how should I loop my program? or make corrections with the methods I'm using... Any help would be appreciated :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
    String[] word = new String[22];


    word[0] = "Package";
    word[1] = "Import";
    word[2] = "Public";
    word[3] = "Private";
    word[4] = "Static";
    word[5] = "Void";
    word[6] = "String";
    word[7] = "Integer";
    word[8] = "Character";
    word[9] = "Boolean";
    word[10] = "Public";
    word[11] = "High-Level";
    word[12] = "Low-Level";
    word[13] = "Class";
    word[14] = "Statements";
    word[15] = "Constructor";
    word[16] = "Default";
    word[17] = "Method";
    word[18] = "Declaration";
    word[19] = "Object";
    word[20] = "Variable";
    word[21] = "Null";

    String rword = word[(int) (Math.random() * word.length)];
    Shuffle srword = new Shuffle();
    srword.shuffle(rword,rword);

}
public void shuffle(String input,String rword) throws InterruptedException{
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c:input.toCharArray()){
        boolean scword = characters.add(c);
    }
    StringBuilder scrmbldword = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    while(!characters.isEmpty()){
        int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
        scrmbldword.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
    }

    // Game loads the game xD
    System.out.print("\rLoading");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading.");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading..");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading...");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading....");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading.....");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("\rLoading.....");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.print("\rCompleted");

    // Game introduces itself to the user.
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("\rWelcome to Scramble PT!");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("This is a game where you guess a word that is scrambled.");

    // Game request name input from the user
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("First, What is your Name?");
    String name = scanner.next();

    // Game prints name input from the user
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ",Please get ready because the game is Starting!");

    // Game ask the user for Y/N input
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.print("Are you ready?: ");
    String yon = scanner.next();

    switch (yon) {
        case "Yes":
            // Game prints the Scrambled Word
            System.out.print("Scrambled Word: ");
            System.out.print(scrmbldword.toString());
            // Game let user enter it's guess
            System.out.print("\nEnter your Answer: ");
            String answer;
            boolean win;
            win = false;

                while (win == false){
                   answer = scanner.next();  
                if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase(rword)){                       
                    System.out.println("Wrong, please Try Again!");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.print("Enter your Answer: ");
                    continue;
                }else{     
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.print(String.format("Thanks for playing %s!",name));
                    win = true;
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to try again?");
                    System.out.println("Enter Yes or No: ");
                    String retry = scanner.next();
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                        if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Alright! reloading the game");

                            return;
                        }else 
                            if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                            System.out.println(String.format("Goodbye! %s !",name));
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down..");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down...");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down....");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.....");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("I can't understand you.... So.... Bye!");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down..");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down...");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down....");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.....");    
                            }break;
             }
                }
        case "No":
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("Ok, Please come again!");
            break;
        default:
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.print("Please answer exactly Yes or No!");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code shows that you know about `for` and `while` loops already.  It's unclear to me what else you think you need to know to do what you ask.

Comment: I wanted to have a condition that restarts the whole program... if possible

Comment: Like putting a `for` or `while` loop around the whole contents of the `main` method?  I mean, if you want to loop then you use one of Java's loop constructs.  You make the scope of the construct encompass everything you want to repeat.  I'm having trouble seeing where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for, but before you take and use this code, consider these few things: the way your code is written is not maximizing the use of Java being object oriented. This code would be far more legible and better in general should it have more than one class. The Main class should only be used to initialize another class or group of classes. Okay so now for the code. This should do the trick:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startGame();
    }
    public static void shuffle(String input,String rword) throws InterruptedException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
        for(char c:input.toCharArray()){
            boolean scword = characters.add(c);
        }
        StringBuilder scrmbldword = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        while(!characters.isEmpty()){
            int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
            scrmbldword.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }

        // Game loads the game xD
        System.out.print("\rLoading");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading.");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading..");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading...");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading....");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading.....");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print("\rLoading.....");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.print("\rCompleted");

        // Game introduces itself to the user.
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("\rWelcome to Scramble PT!");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("This is a game where you guess a word that is scrambled.");

        // Game request name input from the user
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("First, What is your Name?");
        String name = scanner.next();

        // Game prints name input from the user
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Hello " + name + ",Please get ready because the game is Starting!");

        // Game ask the user for Y/N input
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.print("Are you ready?: ");
        String yon = scanner.next();

        switch (yon.toLowerCase()) {
            case "yes":
                // Game prints the Scrambled Word
                System.out.print("Scrambled Word: ");
                System.out.print(scrmbldword.toString());
                // Game let user enter it's guess
                System.out.print("\nEnter your Answer: ");
                String answer;
                boolean win;
                win = false;

                while (!win){
                    answer = scanner.next();
                    if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase(rword)){
                        System.out.println("Wrong, please Try Again!");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        System.out.print("Enter your Answer: ");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        System.out.print(String.format("Thanks for playing %s!",name));
                        win = true;
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        System.out.println(" Would you like to try again?");
                        System.out.println("Enter Yes or No: ");
                        String retry = scanner.next();
                        Thread.sleep(500);

                        if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                            System.out.println("Alright! reloading the game");
                            startGame();
                            return;
                        }else
                        if (retry.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                            System.out.println(String.format("Goodbye! %s !",name));
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down..");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down...");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down....");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.....");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("I can't understand you.... So.... Bye!");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down..");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down...");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down....");
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                            System.out.println("\rGame Shutting down.....");
                        }break;
                    }
                }
            case "no":
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.print("Ok, Please come again!");
                break;
            default:
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.print("Please answer exactly Yes or No!");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void startGame() {
        String[] word = new String[22];

        word[0] = "Package";
        word[1] = "Import";
        word[2] = "Public";
        word[3] = "Private";
        word[4] = "Static";
        word[5] = "Void";
        word[6] = "String";
        word[7] = "Integer";
        word[8] = "Character";
        word[9] = "Boolean";
        word[10] = "Public";
        word[11] = "High-Level";
        word[12] = "Low-Level";
        word[13] = "Class";
        word[14] = "Statements";
        word[15] = "Constructor";
        word[16] = "Default";
        word[17] = "Method";
        word[18] = "Declaration";
        word[19] = "Object";
        word[20] = "Variable";
        word[21] = "Null";

        String rword = word[(int) (Math.random() * word.length)];
        try {
            shuffle(rword,rword);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have any further questions regarding my post or my additions, feel free to ask me here, or DM me here https://twitter.com/sethsource1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly mate: 
- Main method should generally have the bare minimum code. A main method should really just initialise the program and start it and that is it so move some of that stuff to a constructor or elsewhere

Anyways, what you are doing is functional sure, but try not to get in bad habits: break your code up into smaller chunks by calling methods from within other methods. This will make debugging far easier and make it way easier for others to read. However, you are doing some good stuff like giving your variables decent names, and you are a beginner so making stuff functional is step one so you're doing good.

Regarding your question, you want to loop the entire program when really you want to loop a key method in your program, the program itself does not need to be looped ever and that's not a goal to work towards. A program cannot loop itself because what is going to loop it (only another program can do that)?

So, what you need to do is take the initiation stuff out of the main method and instead put it in a different method that you can call from the main method. In this new method create your while loop with your game initiation code inside and call this method from the main method after initiating an instance of your class (main method is static so have to create your class as a variable inside).

So do something like this:

```
 //Make a new class containing just the main method
 public static void main(String[] args){
  //Substitute Class for the name of your class and initiate it as below
  Class myClass = new Class():
  //
  myClass.initiate();
  }

  //Then in your actual action class 
  public void initiate(){
  while(condition){
   //call the shuffle method inside a while loop, if you want to initiate inside too 
   //then have your array building stuff in a method you call here too
   buildArray();
   shuffle();
   } 
  }
```

Hope this helps bro

Answer (score 0):

Lazy option 1: wrap the contents of the main() in a while(true){*whatever is inside main*}

Lazy option 2: create a new thread at the end where you want to start again, new Thread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ main(null); } }).start();

**What the assignment probably is for**:  add some question to the end to ask if you want to play again and if yes, loop the game again somehow.

I have to ask though, why the fake loading screen?